# The fraction $b_n/a_n$ converging to $1$ while $b_n \to 0$ and $a_n \to 0$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

posted here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351749/division-arithmetic-converging

and was told to ask again here with more info.

so given $a_n$→0

and, $\frac{b_n }{a_n}$ → 1

prove $b_n$→0

I tried the following:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow ∞}\frac{b_n}{a_n}=1$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow ∞}\frac{b_n}{a_n}-1=1-1=0$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow ∞}(1+\frac{-b_n}{a_n})^{\frac{1}{a_n}^{a_n}}=0$$

so here I got stuck saying $e^{0} = 1 $ and not 0

second way I tried:

given $\varepsilon$ > 0 there is $N_1$ so for every n>$N_1$ there is:
$|a_n - a| < \varepsilon$

given $\varepsilon$ > 0 there is $N_2$ so for every n>$N_2$ there is:

$|\frac{b_n}{a_n} - 1| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

$|\frac{b_n-a_n}{a_n}| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

and now I'll make a smaller fraction:

$|\frac{b_n-a_n}{a_n+2}| <|\frac{b_n-a_n}{a_n}| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

I'll define $N_\max$ = max{$N_1, N_2$} so for every n>$N_\max$ there is:

$|\frac{b_n-0}{0+2}| <|\frac{b_n-a_n}{a_n}| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

$|\frac{b_n}{2}| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$
$b_n < \frac{2\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$

when n$\rightarrow$ ∞ < $\varepsilon$
so $b_n$ = 0 = a

I just don't know if this is right because I learn calculus alone and there is no answer

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $a_n \to a = 0$?  Do you mean that $a_n$ converges to zero?  Or, did you mean to write $a_n \to a$, where $a \neq 0$?

Comment: I mean $a_n$ converges to zero

Comment: If we're given that $a_n \to 0$, then it's strange that you have decided to use the letter $a$.

Comment: I'm sorry i'll change that, I copied the given information from the first section of the question, this is the second section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} {b_n}=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{b_n}{a_n} \cdot a_n\right) = 
\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n}\right)\cdot \left({\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n}\right)=1\cdot 0=0
$$

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Comment: man, this is way too short than I expected... Thank you for the answer